# Web Scraping a data inside an html h3 tag using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to grab a certain data using selenium, the data is located inside a  tag with a similar class, so how do I grab it?

[image]

Those 2 are the data, but they are inside the same class.
i tried to use

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name
```

But it doesn't work, is there a way to grab it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following xpath `"//*[@class='card-title']"` and use the function `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`. In order to check the correctness of the xpath, inspect the page and with Control + F or Command + F put the xpath in the search bar so you will see if the xpath finds the elements you are looking for

Then if you want the text inside:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='card-title']")
data = [element.text for element in elements]
```

Answer (score 1):

yes there is you can grab the first one like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//h3[@class='cart-title'])[1]").find_element_by_tag_name('b').text
```

and the second one like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//h3[@class='cart-title'])[2]").find_element_by_tag_name('b').text
```